# strange javascript error in console

Tags: javascript

I never seen this kind of error in console:

```
Received message of type object from http://mysiteDotcome, expected a string all.js:56
Received message of type object from http://mysiteDOTcom, expected a string
```

my app work fine but I still curious about this errors, any idea?

Comment: Can you post relevant parts of all.js?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, and here you can read a solution, at least it works for me :) [Gigya websites throw an error: Received message of type object from (domain), expected a string - all.js:56](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503781/gigya-websites-throw-an-error-received-message-of-type-object-from-domain-ex)

the problem was the FVD Downloader extension.

Answer (score 0):

It says that in your javascript, a string value is expected in return, but an object is found. This means your `Accept` header has something like `text/plain`.

Comment: what is Accept header?

Comment: @ATOzTOA Ignoring a warning doesn't solve it - it's ignoring it.