# Gigya websites throw an error: Received message of type object from (domain), expected a string - all.js:56

Tags: facebook, gigya

I have just noticed that all my websites using Gigya throw the following console log message for Facebook:

> Received message of type object from (domain), expected a string -
>   all.js:56

Does anyone know why this message occurs or how to fix this?

Just noticed its something to do with the facebook-send button. If I remove that it is fine.

Answer (score 5):

My friend had the same problem with you.
We disabled a chrome extension named "FVD Downloader" and the message just disappeared.
So try to remove/disable the chrome extension one by one on your computer.
Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Facebook sdk is overeager about claiming messages. If you use `postMessage()` at all with objects you'll run into this. This was reported as a bug, and closed as "by design" last year -- which is unfortunate, because the way this clutters up the console logs is really, really annoying.

I just filed a bug report asking for the original bug report about this to be re-opened, and you can subscribe and add any comments you have here:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/612223468855371/
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/857134114375190/
```